# Wtiting log files from pubsub logs to bucket with custom directory name and file name based out of log time

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am parsing logs from pubsub and aim is to put those logs in hourly files in custom location which is again based on log timestamp(field inside pubsub log).

Files should get all data for the particular hours. File should keep on appending on hourly basis.
e.g. gs://bucket/applog/2017-09-27/application1/app-2017-09-27-11H.log

```
pushFilePColl.apply(Window.into(new FileTextIOWindowFn())) .apply("FileTO to LOG TextIO", ParDo.of(new TextIOWriteDoFn())) .apply(TextIO.write().to(pipelineOptions.getFileStorage‌​Bucket()).withWindow‌​edWrites() .withFilenamePolicy(new FileStorageFileNamePolicy(logTypeEnum)).withNumShards(10));
```

Custom window :

```
public class FileTextIOWindowFn extends NonMergingWindowFn<Object, IntervalWindow> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private IntervalWindow assignWindow(AssignContext context) {
    FilePushTO filePushTO = (FilePushTO) context.element();
    String timestamp = filePushTO.getLogTime();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(CommonConstants.DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_SSS)
            .withZoneUTC();
    Instant start_point = Instant.parse(timestamp, formatter);
    Calendar cal = DateUtil.getCurrentDateInUTC();
    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMATER_PARTITION_NAME = DateUtil.getDateFormater();
    Instant end_point = Instant.parse(DATE_FORMATER_PARTITION_NAME.format(cal.getTime()), formatter);
    return new IntervalWindow(start_point, end_point);
};

@Override
public Coder<IntervalWindow> windowCoder() {
    return IntervalWindow.getCoder();
}

@Override
public Collection<IntervalWindow> assignWindows(AssignContext c) throws Exception {
    return Arrays.asList(assignWindow(c));
}

@Override
public boolean isCompatible(WindowFn<?, ?> other) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public WindowMappingFn<IntervalWindow> getDefaultWindowMappingFn() {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Attempted to get side input window for GlobalWindow from non-global WindowFn");
}
```

}

File name Policy :

```
public class FileStorageFileNamePolicy extends FileBasedSink.FilenamePolicy {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileStorageFileNamePolicy.class);

private LogTypeEnum logTypeEnum;

public FileStorageFileNamePolicy(LogTypeEnum logTypeEnum) {
    this.logTypeEnum = logTypeEnum;
}

@Override
public ResourceId windowedFilename(ResourceId outputDirectory, WindowedContext context, String extension) {
    IntervalWindow window = (IntervalWindow) context.getWindow();
    String startDate = window.start().toString();
    String dateString = startDate.replace("T", CommonConstants.SPACE)
            .replaceAll(startDate.substring(startDate.indexOf("Z")), CommonConstants.EMPTY_STRING);
    String startDateHour = startDate;
    try {
        startDate = DateUtil.getDateForFileStore(dateString, null);
        startDateHour = DateUtil.getDTLocalTZHour(dateString, null);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error converting date  : {}", e);
    }
    String filename = new StringBuilder(window.start().toString()).append(CommonConstants.COLON)
            .append(startDateHour).append(CommonConstants.UNDER_SCORE).append(context.getShardNumber())
            .append(".txt").toString();
    String dirName = new StringBuilder(startDate).append(CommonConstants.FORWARD_SLASH)
            .append(logTypeEnum.getValue().toLowerCase()).append(CommonConstants.FORWARD_SLASH).toString();
    LOGGER.info("Directory : {} and File Name : {}", dirName, filename);
    return outputDirectory.resolve(dirName, ResolveOptions.StandardResolveOptions.RESOLVE_DIRECTORY)
            .resolve(filename, ResolveOptions.StandardResolveOptions.RESOLVE_FILE);
}

@Override
public ResourceId unwindowedFilename(ResourceId outputDirectory, Context context, String extension) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported.");
}
```

}

I made customWindow with Interval window so that in FileNamePolicy I can get appropriate time stamp. I cannot use fixedWindow as It will always give me current timestamp.

In here everything is working perfect but files cannot appended. they are overriden.

Comment: What is the question you are asking? Are you asking about how to subscribe to data in Pub/Sub? How to write data to Google Cloud Storage? How to format the data?

Comment: My Question is how to write in google bucket custom location which is based on runtime decisions like date and other structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `TextIO.write().to(...).withWindowedWrites()`, available in Beam 2.1. See [TextIO javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html#write--).

Comment: I am doing the same way 

pushFilePColl.apply(Window.into(new FileTextIOWindowFn()))
     .apply("FileTO to LOG TextIO", ParDo.of(new TextIOWriteDoFn()))
     .apply(TextIO.write().to(pipelineOptions.getFileStorageBucket()).withWindowedWrites()
       .withFilenamePolicy(new FileStorageFileNamePolicy(logTypeEnum)).withNumShards(10));

Comment: But this is writing one file for each pubsub String. How can I append the logs in log file?

Comment: So files are generated as 


  2017-09-21T09:00:08.306Z:09_2.txt 
 
  2017-09-21T09:00:08.311Z:09_3.txt 
 
  2017-09-21T09:00:08.312Z:09_5.txt

Comment: Strings are not appending... and this is my question.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include this code, including your custom windowing and filename policy functions?

Comment: Edited on your request. In above I can set end time as independent of system timestamp. But main problem here is how to append file?

Comment: GCS does not support appending to blobs. Also, looking at the code, using a custom window fn is definitely the wrong tool for the job. Custom window fns are an extremely advanced API and should almost never be used. It seems like you used it just to assign custom timestamps - for that, use the simple WithTimestamps transform instead.

Comment: Misuse of the window fn is also the reason you're getting 1 element per file. I recommend to update on the windowing section of the programming guide https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing, specifically note that windowing acts as an additional grouping key, and that it's applied only after grouping operations and ignored otherwise.

Comment: The proper way to stream data onto a filesystem that doesn't support appending files is to keep creating new files; you can do that using withWindowedWrites() as indicated in my answer, if your collection is properly windowed as per my previous comment :)

Comment: How to add custom timestamp? When I add it to any other timestamp, I am getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot output with timestamp 2017-08-29T12:26:10.977Z. Output timestamps must be no earlier than the timestamp of the current input (2017-10-03T04:13:09.336Z) minus the allowed skew (0 milliseconds). See the DoFn#getAllowedTimestampSkew() Javadoc for details on changing the allowed skew." because reading from pubsub is in different timstamp.

Comment: In my case pub sub messages are plain strings and don't  have any structure in it, so cannot get exact timestamp field extracted at the time of reading it. So cannot do readString().withTimestampAttribute(). Please suggest.

Comment: I see. Have you tried setting the allowed timestamp skew, as the error message suggests? I presume you're using WithTimestamps, it has a property for controlling that.

Comment: Can you paste sample for setting skew?  I am doing like this <code>String timeStamp = filePushTO.getLogTime();
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(CommonConstants.DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_SSS)
    .withZoneUTC();
  Instant startPoint = Instant.parse(timeStamp, formatter);
pc.output(this.FILE_PUSH_IO, new FilePushTO(logMap.get(BQConstants.LOG_TIME), pc.element()),startPoint);

Comment: Are you using the WithTimestamps transform?

Comment: Can you give me some samples how to use this WithTimestamps transform?

Comment: I believe its javadoc contains a sample, and searching for "beam WithTimestamps" produces a number of additional results containing usage examples. Can you elaborate on what is unclear to you about how to use it, after looking at those examples?